# How to create a `hash` or `md5` from a map in elixir?

Tags: hash, elixir, md5

I need to convert a `map` into a `hash/md5`.

```
map1 = %{k1: "val1", k2: "val2"}
map2 = %{k2: "val2", k1: "val1"}
```

Above both maps are same as order doesn't matter in map.
How to create a hash from map so that their hash are same too ?

I need to do this for caching purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [`phash2/1`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#phash2-1) or [`phash2/2`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#phash2-2) function, we can hash any elixir/erlang term:

```
:erlang.phash2(map1) == :erlang.phash2(map2) # true
```

Answer (score 3):

For MD5:

```rb
:crypto.hash(:md5, :erlang.term_to_binary(%{k1: "val1", k2: "val2"}))
=> <<225, 87, 188, 155, 209, 54, 124, 25, 115, 196, 104, 11, 221, 200, 140, 247>>
```

You can use [`Base`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Base.html) to encode it into a string, if needed:

```rb
:crypto.hash(:md5, :erlang.term_to_binary(map)) |> Base.encode64
=> "4Ve8m9E2fBlzxGgL3ciM9w=="
:crypto.hash(:md5, :erlang.term_to_binary(map)) |> Base.encode16
=> "E157BC9BD1367C1973C4680BDDC88CF7
```

[`:crypto.hash/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html#hash-2) also [works with](http://erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html#type-hash_algorithm) `:sha`, `:sha256`, `:blake2b`, etc.

---

> Above both maps are same as order doesn't matter in map. How to create a hash from map so that their hash are same too ?

It's worth pointing out that maps are unordered in Elixir/Erlang, so the two maps in your example produce the same map internally - the order of the keys in the source code is irrelevant:

```rb
%{k1: "val1", k2: "val2"} == %{k2: "val2", k1: "val1"}
=> true
```

Comment: ETF do not guarantee the same ordering of keys in maps, so there is no guarantee that the returned hash will be the same between different implementations/releases of OTP.

Comment: Good point. If consistency between versions is important, I guess there is no answer to the OP's question short of serializing to some custom intermediate form that you control before hashing.